# Maven unable to download transitive swagger dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, springfox, spring-boot-starter

I have a Spring Boot (2.2.6) project  that has another starter as a dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyX.teamY</groupId>
            <artifactId>Z-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I get a error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class` because of missing

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket

I don't find any springfox under project's external libraries dropdown (in IntelliJ) so I digged into the source of custom starter and found this:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Docket.class)
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("A Sample Project")
                        .version("0.0.1")
                        .build())
                .select()
                .apis(basePackage("com.companyX"))
                .build();
    }
```

But the starter project does have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

in its `pom.xml`. If I add above to my Spring Boot project the error goes away so I am not sure why IntelliJ or maven isn't able to resolve such dependency: `Spring Boot APP -> Custom Starter -/> SpringFox`. What am I missing here?

Versions:

- Java SDK: 1.8.0_231
- Maven: 3.6.2
- SpringBoot: 2.2.6.RELEASE for both projects

I ran `mvn clean install` and did not see any errors. The error only appears for one of those contextloads test method.

EDIT:
After some digging, this looks to be an issue with transitive dependencies not being resolved, but then I followed the steps of running `mvn install` on both projects to no avail.

Comment: Please check the build on plain command line and see possible error message ... which Maven version do you use? Which Java version?